# Variable dimensions in file don't match with dimension of indexing subscript if one dimension is singleton

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I want to test a function `func(par1,par2,par3)` with all combinations of the parameters `par1`, `par2` and `par3` and store the output in a `.mat` file. My code looks like this at the moment:

```
n1 = 3;
n2 = 1;
n3 = 2;

parList1 = rand(1,n1);    % n1,n2,n3 is just some integer
parList2 = rand(1,n2);    % the lists are edited by hand in the actual script
parList3 = rand(1,n3);

saveFile = matfile('file.mat','Writable',true);
% allocate memory    
saveFile.output = NaN(numel(parList1),numel(parList2),numel(parList3));  

counter1 = 0;
for par1 = parList1
    counter1 = counter1 + 1;
    counter2 = 0;    % reset inner counter
   for par2 = parList2
     counter2 = counter2 + 1;
     counter3 = 0;   % reset inner counter
      for par3 = parList3
         counter3 = counter3 + 1;
         saveFile.output(counter1,counter2,counter3) = sum([par1,par2,par3]);
      end
   end
end
```

This works except if `parList3` has only one item, i.e. if `n3 = 1`. Then the `saveFile.output` has singleton dimensions and I get the error

```
Variable 'output' has 2 dimensions in the file, this does not match the 3 dimensions in the indexing subscripts.
```

Is there a elegant way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in the `for` statement needs to be a *row array*, not a column array as in your example.  The loops will exit after the first value with your code.  Set a breakpoint on the `saveFile.output` command to see what I mean.  **With a column array**, `par1` will not be a scalar as desired, but the whole `parList1` column.  **With a row array**, `par1` will iterate through each value of `parList1` as intended

Another thing is that you need to **reset your inner counters** (`counter2` and `counter2`) or your second and third dimensions will blow up larger than you expected.

The `n3=1` problem is expected behavior because `matfile` defines the variables with fixed number of dimensions and it will treat `saveFile.output` as 2D.  Once you have fixed those issues, you can solve the `n3=1` problem by changing the line,

```
saveFile.output(counter1,counter2,counter3) = sum([par1,par2,par3]);
```

to

```
if n3==1, saveFile.output(counter1,counter2) = sum([par1,par2,par3]);
else saveFile.output(counter1,counter2,counter3) = sum([par1,par2,par3]);
end
```

Comment: You are right about both points. I fixed the code in the question. I also found out that there is only a problem if the _last_ dimension is singleton (´n3 = 1`).

Comment: I think that's expected behavior with `matfile` variables, but I added a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

By now I realized that actually in matfiles all the singleton dimensions, except for the first two are removed.

In my actual programm I decided to save the data in the file linearly and circumvent matfile's lack of linear indexing capability by using the functions `sub2ind` and `ind2sub`.